# IIS + Service Fabric + URLACL

Tags: iis, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to run IIS in Service Fabric, using Hostable Web Core.

The problem, I think, is that Service Fabric is setting up URLs for `http://+:12345` and `http://localhost:12345`, but IIS really wants a URLACL for `http://*:12345`. With the asterisk. A weak wildcard.

So I'm looking for a solution that isn't me just making my own setup entry point. Though, that's where I'm heading.

Either a way to make IIS register a strong binding, or a way to make Service Fabric allocate a weak URLACL.

Ideas?

Comment: I did "work around" this issue by using a `SetupEntryPoint` to run custom netsh commands to manipulate the bindings to how I want them. But I'm not happy with this, so the question is still open.

Comment: Can you put that as one of the answers ? Can be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to install the full blown IIS (or anything else) on your service fabric cluster, it can be done automatically by specifying a setup script in the `CodePackage` element of your `ServiceManifest.xml` file.

See the example below:

```
<CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
  <SetupEntryPoint>
    <ExeHost>
      <Program>Scripts\install.bat</Program>
    </ExeHost>
  </SetupEntryPoint>
  <EntryPoint>
    <ExeHost>
      <Program>MyService.exe</Program>
      <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
    </ExeHost>
  </EntryPoint>
</CodePackage>
```

Then in the root of your project create a folder named `Scripts` (i.e. what we named the folder in the above example) and create two text files inside of it: `install.bat`, and `install-iis.ps1`, change their build actions to `Content` with Copy to Output Directory set to `Copy if newer`*.

(*: pro-tip: don't ever choose `Copy Always`, because Visual Studio will ALWAYS rebuild the project every time you build the solution, even if there are no changes!)

for `install.bat`, the contents should be:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\install-iis.ps1" -force > install-iis.log
```

for `install-iis.ps1`, the contents should be:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process

# Exit early if IIS is already installed.
$installed = (Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online `
    | where { $_.state -eq "Enabled" -and $_.FeatureName -eq "IIS-WebServer" } `
    | Measure-Object).Count;
if ($installed -gt 0) { return; }

# Install IIS and all relevant features.
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServer -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-CommonHttpFeatures -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpErrors -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpRedirect -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationDevelopment -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-NetFxExtensibility45 -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpLogging -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-LoggingLibraries -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-RequestMonitor -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpTracing -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Security -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-RequestFiltering -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Performance -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerManagementTools -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Metabase -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ManagementConsole -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-BasicAuthentication -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WindowsAuthentication -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-StaticContent -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-DefaultDocument -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebSockets -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationInit -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45 -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIExtensions -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIFilter -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpCompressionStatic -All
```

And, now comes the fun part -- you have to set the code package to run as an admin! (otherwise, you can't do fun things like installing IIS!) -- This took me a while to figure out and nail down, but, you need to go to the Service Fabric project (the .sfproj file in your solution), and find the `ApplicationManifest.xml` file.

At the very end of the file, as the last child of the `ApplicationManifest` element, add a `Principals` and a `Policies` element:

```
<Principals>
  <Users>
    <User Name="SfAdminUser" AccountName="SfAdminUser">
      <MemberOf>
        <SystemGroup Name="Administrators" />
      </MemberOf>
    </User>
  </Users>
</Principals>
<Policies>
  <DefaultRunAsPolicy UserRef="SfAdminUser" />
</Policies>
```

Now find the corresponding `ServiceManifestImport` element for your service, and add a `Policies` element, as the last child:

```
<ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="MyService.Pkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
  <ConfigOverrides>
  [ . . . redacted . . . ]
  </ConfigOverrides>
  <Policies>
    <RunAsPolicy CodePackageRef="Code" UserRef="SfAdminUser" EntryPointType="All" />
  </Policies>
</ServiceManifestImport>
```

There you go.  Now when you install your service, it will ensure that IIS is present on the machine.

(You can perform additional setup actions, such as setting up your site in IIS in additional `.ps1` files, and add lines in the bat file for each one -- make sure to set the additional files at `Content` and `Copy if newer`!)

Comment: I'm not interested in IIS being present though, I'm interested in having a URLACL made by Service Fabric.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't bother with Hostable Web Core, it's completely outdated. The way to get IIS running on Service Fabric is to run IIS in a Windows Container and let Service Fabric manage the container. Here's a tutorial that guides you through it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-host-app-in-a-container

Although that tutorial uses Docker Compose, it's not required; you can specify a container in ServiceManifest.xml if you don't want to deal with Docker Compose.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't really an option. Need a domain joined machine.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to use netsh in a setup entry point script, and change ServiceManifest.xml <Endpoint> from protocol="http" to protocol="tcp" so SF doesn't create an ACL for you.

Comment: Any idea how to clean these up at application restart or shutdown?

Comment: You can just install the IIS feature using a powershell script in your code package's `SetupEntryPoint`.